# Why fixture.detectChanges() is required for a unit test [Jasmine/Karma]

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm learning Unit testing with Jasmine and Karma. My test case is passing but I do not understand one thing. Here's my typescript:

```
// array list of objects where each month will have one object i.e. 12 objects (Jan to Dec)
monthsData: Array<{
    monthName: string;
    monthYear: number;
    isInRange: boolean;
    isLowerEdge: boolean;
    isUpperEdge: boolean;
}>;

rangeState: { edge1Exists: boolean; edge2Exists: boolean; edgeIndexes: Array<number> };

initRangeState() {} <---- method which should be called; Not important for this question
```

And here's my test case in spec file:

```
it('should re-initialize range state when reflection is triggered', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges(); <--- why this is required ?
    const rangeState = { edge1Exists: true, edge2Exists: true, edgeIndexes: [] };
    const monthsData = {
        monthName: 'Jan',
        monthYear: 2020,
        isInRange: true,
        isLowerEdge: true,
        isUpperEdge: false
    };
    fixture.componentInstance.rangeState = rangeState;
    fixture.componentInstance.monthsData[0] = monthsData;
    ...
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.initRangeState).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I do not understand that when I passed dummy `rangeState` and `monthsData` already. Then why I need to run `fixture.detectChanges()` in first place. My test case is failing without calling that. Please tell me the reason behind it. I'm sure there is something that I don't know.
Here's the screenshot when `fixture.detectChanges()` is removed:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios:

> You must tell the TestBed to perform data binding by calling
> fixture.detectChanges().

[...]

> Delayed change detection is intentional and useful. It gives the
> tester an opportunity to inspect and change the state of the component
> before Angular initiates data binding and calls lifecycle hooks.